# The Origin viewcontroller's weird behavior when it presents new landscape Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode

I setup one portrait Viewcontroller(referred to as PVC) presenting a landscape Viewcontroller(referred to as LVC).
When the PVC actually presents the LVC, the LVC shows above the PVC and works fine, but PVC's collectionView re-calculates cell size 'unintentionally' and collapses its view.

Here's what I did:

1. In the Xcode settings, I allowed portrait and landscape orientation for having one LVC and other PVCs in the app.
2. I made one Viewcontroller overriding supportedInterfaceOrientations method returning '.landscape' and other Viewcontrollers returning '.portrait'.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. 
The reason it caused the error was that I put collectionView in the PVC as the most parental position. 
I had to put UIView as the most parental position containing collectionView.